# Open local text file in Javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to open a text file on the computer and have the contents of the file to be a variable. I plan to take the contents of a TXT file and place them into a DIV so I can view the contents of the text file on the web server.

Comment: Please read [ask] and be more specific about what you are trying to do, what research you have done and what you have tried to solve problem yourself. This isn't a code writing service and you are expected to have done basic research. Searching the web for solutions in both languages is not difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `javascript`:

You can use the JavaScript **File Reader** API. Take a look here for some examples: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/, Here is the API reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader